# SQL Server : how to retrieve top group id from same table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL Server 2008 R2.

My source table looks like this:

```
EmpID      Name   GroupID
-------------------------
1-KFX       xxx    7-ZQMN
7-ZQMN      yyy    null
AXM-4       zzz    1-KFX
7-ZQOP      JJJ    QRS-0
QRS-0       kkk    null
```

and so on....

I need to traverse through table to get `Top GroupID` (Top in the hierarchy) for each `EmpID` until  `GroupID` is null, and populate `EmpID` if `GroupID` is null

I am trying to write a query to achieve results like below, any help is appreciated.

```
EmpID    Name   TopGroupID
------------------------
1-KFX    xxx        7-ZQMN
7-ZQMN   yyy        7-ZQMN
AXM-4    zzz        7-ZQMN
7-ZQOP   JJJ        QRS-0
QRS-0    kkk        QRS-0
```

Comment: what does it mean by toplevel group id?

Comment: @KTP What do you meant by top level? is it mean Maximum?

Comment: Top group id is an EmpID where GroupID is null.  I need to traverse through table iteratively using Table.GroupID = Table.EmpID, to find out Top GroupID.

Comment: Hi, I edited my content for more clarity. EmpIDs and GroupIDs are not actually numbers. I need to find out top Group id (top in the hierarchy) for each EmpID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hierarchy problem is solved by using a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to find the root node.

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(EmpID VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,Name VARCHAR(128),GroupID VARCHAR(128));
INSERT INTO #tt(EmpID,Name,GroupID)VALUES
    ('1-KFX','xxx','7-ZQMN'),
    ('7-ZQMN','yyy',null),
    ('AXM-4','zzz','1-KFX'),
    ('7-ZQOP','JJJ','QRS-0'),
    ('QRS-0','kkk',null);

;WITH cte_tr AS (
    SELECT EmpId, GroupID, depth=0
    FROM #tt
    UNION ALL -- what follows is the recursion in the CTE to find the parent, keeping track of depth
    SELECT cte_tr.EmpID, GroupId=t.GroupID, depth=cte_tr.depth+1
    FROM cte_tr 
         INNER JOIN #tt AS t ON 
             t.EmpID=cte_tr.GroupID
    WHERE t.GroupID IS NOT NULL
),
cte_depth AS ( -- select the maximum depth for a starting node
    SELECT EmpID, max_depth=MAX(depth)
    FROM cte_tr
    GROUP BY EmpID
)
SELECT cte_depth.EmpID, TopGroupId=ISNULL(cte_tr.GroupID,cte_tr.EmpID)
FROM cte_depth 
     INNER JOIN cte_tr ON -- select the nodes at the maximum depth
         cte_tr.EmpID=cte_depth.EmpID AND 
         cte_tr.depth=cte_depth.max_depth
ORDER BY cte_tr.EmpID;

DROP TABLE #tt;
```

Result:

```
+--------+------------+
| EmpID  | TopGroupId |
+--------+------------+
| 1-KFX  | 7-ZQMN     |
| 7-ZQMN | 7-ZQMN     |
| 7-ZQOP | QRS-0      |
| AXM-4  | 7-ZQMN     |
| QRS-0  | QRS-0      |
+--------+------------+
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I edited my content for more clarity.  EmpIDs and GroupIDs are not actually numbers.  I need to find out top Group id (top in the hierarchy) for each EmpID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select
    empid,
    name
    isnull(max(GroupID),empid) 'TopGroupId'
    from tablename
    group by 
    empid,name
    order by empid
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I edited my content for more clarity.  EmpIDs and GroupIDs are not actually numbers.  I need to find out top Group id (top in the hierarchy) for each EmpID.